# In Redux, is it necessary to do deep copy

Tags: reactjs, redux

The below object is `action.data` has a nested object `address`

```
{
    name: 'Ben',
    address: {
        country: 'Australia',
        state: 'NSW'
    }
}
```

How should I handle it in the reducer?

```
const rootReducer = (state = initState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        switch RECEIVE_DATA:
            return {...state, data: action.data}
    }
}
```

Can I do it as above? that I just assign the whole object to `data` without copying?

or

```
const rootReducer = (state = initState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        switch RECEIVE_DATA:
            const address = {...action.data.address}
            const data = {...action.data, address}
            return {...state, data}
    }
}
```

Or should I do a deep copy of the object and assign it to `data`?
thanks

Comment: it definitely is! If your state has several other objects/array inside of it you should definitely make a deep copy, at least the changed ones. Because of this I've been struggling what's wrong with my app for a day!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The "correct" way to handle updates of nested data is with multiple shallow copies, one for each level of nesting.  It's also certainly okay to create a new object that just replaces one field completely, per your first example.

See the Redux docs section on [Immutable Update Patterns](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns/) for some info on how to properly do immutable updates, and also the Redux FAQ entry regarding [deep cloning](https://redux.js.org/faq/performance#do-i-have-to-deep-clone-my-state-in-a-reducer-isnt-copying-my-state-going-to-be-slow).

Comment: "It's also certainly okay to create a new object that just replaces one field completely, per your first example" Sorry, I don't get your point. In the first exmaple, state.data.address and action.data.address are pointing to the same reference, is this fine? thanks

Comment: In other words, doing `return {...state, data : action.data}` is fine.

Comment: dead link: "avoiding deep cloning."

Answer (score 22):

From Redux:

> Common Redux misconception: you need to deeply clone the state. Reality: if something inside doesn't change, keep its reference the same!

Comment: Take case when initialising state (using `function myReducer(state = someObject, action)`). At that stage ALL of the state is changing so deep cloning may be necessary. Specifically I found that deep cloning was necessary when having multiple instances of an app a page, to avoid data sharing between the two instances. To do that I used `function myReducer(state = { ...someObject }, action)` and made sure that `someObject` didn't contain any arrays or objects).

Comment: @AndyCastles This probably means that you're mutating a prop in the state in a reducer without shallow copying it before (you're changing it, so you do need a shallow copy). You can define an initial state with `const INITIAL_STATE = {counters: [1]};` and then the reducer with `function incrementCounterReducer(state=INITIAL_STATE) { const newState = { ...state, counters: [...state.counters] }; newState.counters[0]++; return newState; }`. Then, with `console.log(INITIAL_STATE.counters, incrementCounterReducer().counters)` you'll see that we're not mutating `INITIAL_STATE.counters`.

Answer (score 0):

No, shallow copy of Unchanged properties.
Changed properties will be anyway new values, so no question of type of copy.
In code we achieve it like this `return {...prevState}`

Answer (score -3):

If you are changing only one item in an array, Redux docs says you can use array.map, but if you know the index, this is faster:

```
     state[action.args.index] = {
        ...state[action.args.index],
        disregardLeafNode: action.args.checked
     }
     return state
```

Comment: Please don't do that! You are mutating the state here! You still need to do `map` and replace the concerned item. More: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48806986/what-are-the-consequences-of-mutating-state-in-a-reducer