# Redux: will this be the same state after I change a property of an element in state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I am working on the reducer file which looks like this:

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
  let index

  switch (action.type){

    case "ADD_QUOTE":
     return [...state,action.quote]

    case "REMOVE_QUOTE":
      return state.filter(q=>q.id !==action.quoteId)

    case "UPVOTE_QUOTE":

       index = state.findIndex(quote => quote.id === action.quoteId);
       let quote = state[index];

       return [
         ...state.slice(0, index),
         Object.assign({}, quote, { votes: quote.votes += 1 }),
         ...state.slice(index + 1)
       ];


    default: 
    return state
}
  }
```

I have two ways to implement case `UPVOTE_QUOTE`, the first one is in the above code, and the second one looks like this:

```
...
    case "UPVOTE_QUOTE":
       let quote = state.find(q=>q.id===action.quoteId)
       quote.votes +=1
       return state
...
```

I wonder what is the difference. And in the second situation, what I am not sure is, if I change the `votes` property in that one `quote` element in `state`, when I return the `state`, will it be the state with the new `quote`? And is this `state` the original `state` or a new `state` that refers to a new place? Very confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option looks to be correct. The second option would be mutating the state.

These links that may help explain further: [Mutating Redux State Consequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48806986/what-are-the-consequences-of-mutating-state-in-a-reducer) and [Why cant state be mutated....](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/758)