# Why need I use this.props.user.user.displayName and not this.props.user.displayName? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux

I'm having a little problem at trying to save my firebase user data into the Redux store, I have already tried a lot of waysto save the data in a my store like that:

```
const initialState = {
  logged: null,
  user: {}
};
```

Inside my user object I want all data from my firebase. I send the data like that:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    store.dispatch({
      type: "USER_LOGIN",
      payload: { user: { ...user.providerData[0] } }
    });
  } else {
    store.dispatch({ type: "USER_LOGOUT" });
  }
});
```

Why when am I trying to acces to the data need I to use 
    this.props.user.user.displayName? With the couple of user, note that if I use only one user i receive undefined (Obviusly).

Comment: try `payload: { ...user.providerData[0] }`

Comment: could also do a `console.dir(user)` after your `if (user) {` if you want to see what you're getting back

Comment: Ahh, damm, thanks you bro. One hour trying and...

Comment: { ...user.providerData[0] } work very very good. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    store.dispatch({
      type: "USER_LOGIN",
      payload: user.providerData[0]
    });
  } else {
    store.dispatch({ type: "USER_LOGOUT" });
  }
});
```

Does that work?  Just modified `payload`.

Comment: Yea, that's work but is better send a object, like this. { ...user.providerData[0] }. I set your answer to working. Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is it better to send `{ ...user.providerData[0] }`?  That is more computationally heavy, when it accomplishes the same thing as `payload: user.providerData[0]`.  It also uses more memory, creating a shallow copy.

Comment: Yep? Lol I'dont know, I' be ask later to teacher that's teachs it online. Really I'm a noob and I'm learning seeing the code of others

Comment: I've seen it a lot in Redux stuff. I think it's something to do with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43153020/1512654